# Nasty race conditions with Celluloid

Tags: ruby, celluloid

I have a script that generates a user-specified number of IP addresses and tries to connect to them all on some port. I'm using Celluloid with this script to allow for reasonable speeds, since scanning 2000 hosts synchronously could take a long time. However, say I tell the script to scan 2000 random hosts. What I find is that it actually only ends up scanning about half that number. If I tell it to scan 3000, I get the same basic results. It seems to work much better if I do 1000 or less, but even if I just scan 1000 hosts it usually only ends up doing about 920 with relative consistency. I realize that generating random IP addresses will obviously fail with some of them, but I find it hard to believe that there are around 70 improperly generated IP addresses, every single time. So here's the code:

```
class Scan
include Celluloid

def initialize(arg1)
    @arg1 = arg1
    @host_arr = []
    @timeout = 1
end


def popen(host)
    addr = Socket.getaddrinfo(host, nil)
    sock = Socket.new(Socket.const_get(addr[0][0]), Socket::SOCK_STREAM, 0)

    begin
        sock.connect_nonblock(Socket.pack_sockaddr_in(22, addr[0][3]))

    rescue Errno::EINPROGRESS
        resp = IO.select(nil, [sock], nil, @timeout.to_i)

        if resp.nil?
            puts "#{host}:Firewalled"
        end

        begin
            if sock.connect_nonblock(Socket.pack_sockaddr_in(22, addr[0][3]))
               puts "#{host}:Connected"
            end

        rescue Errno::ECONNREFUSED
            puts "#{host}:Refused"
          rescue
              false
        end
    end
    sock
end


def asynchronous
    s = 1
    threads = []

        while s <= @arg1.to_i do
            @host_arr << Array.new(4){rand(254)}.join('.')
            s += 1
        end

        @host_arr.each do |ip|
            threads << Thread.new do
                begin
                    popen(ip)
                rescue
                end
            end
        end

        threads.each do |thread|
            thread.join
        end
end

end

scan = Scan.pool(size: 100, args: [ARGV[0]])

(0..20).to_a.map { scan.future.asynchronous }
```

Around half the time I get this:

> D, [2014-09-30T17:06:12.810856 #30077] DEBUG -- : Terminating 11 actors...
>    W, [2014-09-30T17:06:12.812151 #30077]  WARN -- : Terminating task: type=:finalizer, meta={:method_name=>:**shutdown**}, status=:receiving
>       Celluloid::TaskFiber backtrace unavailable. Please try `Celluloid.task_class = Celluloid::TaskThread` if you need backtraces here.

and the script does nothing at all. The rest of the time (only if I specify more then 1000) I get this: http://pastebin.com/wTmtPmc8

So, my question is this. How do I avoid race conditions and deadlocking, while still achieving what I want in this particular script?

Answer (score 2):

Starting low-level Threads by yourself interferes with Celluloid's functionality. Instead create a Pool of Scan objects and feed them the IP's all at once. They will queue up for the available

```
class Scan
   def popen
     …
   end
end

scanner_pool = Scan.pool(50)
resulsts = @host_arr.map { |host| scanner_pool.scan(host) }
```